# in React + Redux, when should use response.json()

Tags: reactjs, redux

from the official example, the fetch data from server is done like this:

```
function fetchPosts(subreddit) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestPosts(subreddit))
    return fetch(`http://www.reddit.com/r/${subreddit}.json`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(receivePosts(subreddit, json)))
  }
}
```

so when should I use `response => response.json()`? I have checked the [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json), but still not clear.

Comment: When you want to deserialise the JSON string (stored in a stream) into a JS object.

Comment: @zerkms, so you mean it is similar to JSON.parse()? thanks

Comment: It is not exactly the same, since it returns a promise. But practically what it does - it parses a string with JSON into one of JS types, yep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It depends what you actually requesting and what you wants to do with
>   the response.

For example, if you are requesting for any image, you no need to call `response.json()` rather you will do-

```
var myImage = document.querySelector('.my-image');
fetch('flowers.jpg').then(function(response) {
  return response.blob(); // here 
}).then(function(response) {
  var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(response);
  myImage.src = objectURL;
});
```

if you like to get a javascript object from your `application/json` response, you would like to `parse` as what `JSON.parse()` to work with the response data. That time you need to call `response.json()`.